# FPGA Ressource Estimation

Tags: fpga, dsp

Currently I'm planning my 'first' FPGA project.

I did some VHDL during university, but have no 'practical' experience yet.

Therefore, I'm having a hard time estimating the resources required before starting the design.

**(1) What is required:**

- The system consists of an FPGA, an SPI-Sensor and a UART-Based COM-Link.
- The FPGA needs to act as SPI-Master and configure various registers in the SPI-Sensor after startup.
- Then the Sensor-FIFO needs to be read with an approx. 32kHz rate.
- Then an 1024-Point FFT has to be computed on the samples
- Then the FFT has to be compared against some boundaries (e.g. check if the spectrum contains a value > x... Around 64 such checks, configured through RAM)
- And a custom Register-Based COM-interface has to be served via UART (No heavy lifting... some CRC, some flags but not all features!)

**(2) The Code-Base for a C Project:**

- As this maybe helps to give context to my ideas: I would estimate the required C-Codebase to be around 30kB of flash compiled for ARM M3/M4.

**(3) Question:**

As I have little experience, I need help with a rough estimate of the resources required:

- Number of LABs/CLABs
- Number of Logic-Cells
- Number of RAM-Bits (Distributed and LUTs combined)

Rough estimates are all I'm looking for. Basically, I need an answer to these questions:

- Will it fit into this [device](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/lattice-semiconductor-corporation/ICE40LM4K-SWG25TR50/4571914) yes/no?
- If no, which "order of device" am i looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: Area varies with the speed you require. You need to look at part of your design, perhaps the FFT core, and do a few trial PARs with various target speeds - ie mixes of serial or parallel implementation, and you'll pretty soon get a feel for what the numbers are going to be. Hint, PAR for the largest device first, then target smaller ones if you can.

Comment: I would question the use of an FPGA for this application. Any reasonably competent MCU should be able to handle this entirely in software -- even a Pi Pico ([RP2040](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/rp2040.html) chip) would be overkill. But yes, I think it would fit in an FPGA with 3500 logic cells and 80k bits of memory.

Comment: @DaveTweed I share your opinion. The project is some sort of "excuse" to finally get started :)

Comment: Fair enough! Obviously, you'll need a SPI master module, memory (double buffer) to collect the raw samples, an FFT engine (since you only need to do about 320k "butterflies" per second, this should be straightforward), memory (double buffer) to hold the FFT results, a state machine to do your limit checks, and a UART module. Even if the data is 16 bits, 80k bits of memory should be plenty for all the buffers.